# Xcode 10 build error: 'must declare at least one output file'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I'm trying to get a somewhat complex application built with Xcode 10 so that I can submit it to the store shortly, and I am getting the following error (paths changed for simplicity reason).

`Showing All Errors Only
:-1: shell script build rule for '/Uses/Desktop/ios/app/Vendor/QMServices/QMContactListCache/QMContactListCache/CoreData/QMContactListModel.xcdatamodeld' must declare at least one output file (in target 'QMContactListCache')`

I really have no clue what this means and I am not even sure how to find the target in the project as I don't see it.  It builds in Xcode 9 no problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you claim you're not using the QMServices pod? QuickBlox?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Error removed by deleting duplicate files in the copy bundle resources]

[image: Click on Build phase and click on Copy Bundle Resources]
[image: In my case i have info.pllist duplicate file in bundle,now working fine for me]

**1.Error removed by deleting duplicate files in the copy bundle resources.**
**2.Click on Build phase and click on Copy Bundle Resources.**
**3.In my case i have info.pllist duplicate file in bundle,now working fine for me.**

Answer (score 0):

### To answer the actual question:

- in your target's settings, there's `Build Rules`
- the build rules define how each kind of source-file is converted into something meaningful during build. (e.g. how your .m files are compiled using clang)
- if you add your own file-processing rule, you need to tell the build system, what kind out output your script produces
- you can do this using the `Output Files` table **underneath the script-editor**

### Example:

- you add a processor for `Markdown` files using `Pandoc`

  - it'll convert .md files to .html files
  - the first line of parameters defaults to "Process" `Source files with names matching:` and your pattern is `*.md`
- the second line of parameters can be left as created "Using" `Custom script:` and `Run once per Architecture`.
- your actual script may look like something along these lines

  `pandoc --standalone $INPUT_FILE_PATH --output "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH/$INPUT_FILE_REGION_PATH_COMPONENT$INPUT_FILE_BASE.html"`
- there're more options to be configured: `Dependency file`, `Input Files` and most importantly `Output Files` which is super easy to miss.

  - click on + underneath `Output Files`
  - the value should match what you use in your script (`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/$(INPUT_FILE_REGION_PATH_COMPONENT)$(INPUT_FILE_BASE).html` in this case)
- now you can add Markdown files to your project and simply tick the checkbox under `Target Membership` just like you do to add source-code files to a specific target. But instead of just copying the file to the resource-folder they'll be processed using the configured script and produce HTML files.